# Windows Azure: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\approot\

Tags: c#, azure

I have an xml file in my project that is supposed to be for used for read operations. And it works the project works fine when i run it on my local machine, however it throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\approot\...` when i deploy the worker role.

I have checked that the file exists in that directory.

How can i fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run role in elevated mode...by adding 
< Runtime executionContext ="elevated" /> in csdef.